# Fetching item by checking two mapping tables for user and team

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go, go-gorm

I have an Item table which is mapped with multiple users directly to the item and to some users through a team mapping. currently, I'm using the inner query as below for now

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
WHERE itemId IN (
    SELECT itemId 
    FROM userItemMapping 
    WHERE userId = 1
) 
OR itemId IN (
    SELECT itemId 
    FROM teamItemMapping 
    WHERE teamId IN (
        SELECT TeamId 
        FROM userTeamMapping 
        WHERE userId = 1
    )
)
```

I'm using gorm with go for coding and used raw query to execute this, is there any better way to execute this query or can I improve this by making any changes to my DB.

[image]

How can I use gorm to implement ''' where in ''' to avoid using raw()

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Instead name, and properly qualify, only the columns you actually want returned

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for quick response, I'm not planning to use SELECT * in actual code. since I will be having few joins to item table with some more fileds  I thought i will fine-tune this mapping part first and enter to that.

Comment: But fundamentally, I suspect this comes down to a problem of poor design. One option would be to make all users members of teams, even if that 'team' only has one member.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the word 'never' at the beginning of my comment!!

Comment: @Strawberry I even thought of the same way creating a team with one member, then I felt it won't be good for an end-user to create a team with one member and add mapping to item. is there any other better options for that.